# Decidability of Context free languages

Tags: computability, automata, pushdown-automata

Is is decidable whether 2 given PDAs accept the same language?

Also, is it decidable whether the language accepted by a given grammar is context free (the given grammar could be unrestricted but there may exist an equivalent CFG for it)

Comment: Equality of context-free languages is undecidable, in fact, it is already undecidable for linear context-free languages (in which the derivation always contains just a single nonterminal). See https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/57377

Comment: Please restrict yourself to only one question per post.

Comment: We discourage posts that simply state a problem out of context, and expect the community to solve it. Assuming you tried to solve it yourself and got stuck, it may be helpful if you wrote your thoughts and what you could not figure out. It will definitely draw more answers to your post. Until then, the question will be voted to be closed / downvoted. You may also want to check out [these hints](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98), or use the search engine of this site to find similar questions that were already answered.

Comment: Also, both questions have been answered on [cs.SE] before. I suggest you do some searching.

Comment: Your first question is answered in the obvious place on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language#Decidability.  We expect you to do a significant amount of research before asking (including checking standard resources, like textbooks or Wikipedia), and to show us in the question what research you've done.  If your question is answered in the obvious place on Wikipedia, it would probably benefit you to do more research before asking in the future, as there's little point in us repeating material available in standard resources.

Answer (score -1):

These problems are undecidable. For more other problems, visit this page https://www.cs.wcupa.edu/rkline/fcs/grammar-undecidable.html

Comment: Link-only answers are not worth a lot. If that links break (and it probably will), the content of your answer is almost nil.